# How do I time-out this message box with an auto reboot?

Tags: vbscript, timeout, message, reboot

```
option explicit  
on error resume next


Dim strComputer, intRebootChoice  
Dim objWMIService, objOperatingSystem  
Dim colOperatingSystems 

strComputer = "."


do while 1>0  
 intRebootChoice = msgbox("A system update requires a reboot. Please reboot now by clicking Yes.  Choose No to be asked again in 4 hours.",308,"NOTICE - REBOOT REQUIRED")

select case intRebootChoice  

  case 6  
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
   Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
   For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
    ObjOperatingSystem.Reboot(1)  
   Next 

  case 7  
   wscript.sleep 14400000 

  case else

end select

loop
```

Comment: Do you want the message box to disappear after a certain time?

Answer (score 2):

This uses the `WScript.Shell.Popup` function ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)) to replace the MsgBox. If `Yes` is selected or no button is pressed, the loop ends and the shutdown code is reached.

```
Const NO = 7

    Do While NO = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup( _ 
            "A system update requires a reboot. Please reboot now by clicking Yes.  Choose No to be asked again in 4 hours.", _ 
            10, _ 
            "NOTICE - REBOOT REQUIRED", _ 
            308 _ 
        )
        WScript.Sleep 14400000 
    Loop

    ' Reboot code
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

As [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25030660/1630171) already pointed out: use [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) instead of `MsgBox`. I'd also recommend some other modifications to your code:

- Don't use `On Error Resume Next` *anywhere* without proper error handling routines in place, and **NEVER** use it globally.
- You're using WMI on the local computer only, so there's no point in making the computer configurable via `strComputer`.
- Use named constants instead of literals whenever possible.
- Don't use parentheses around argument lists in "standalone" function/method calls. It only works by coincidence for single arguments and will break when you have more than one. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) for an explanation.
- `Do While True` is easier to understand than `Do While 1>0`.
- An empty `Case Else` is pointless. Remove it.
- `Sleep` is not very accurate with longer periods of time. A more accurate method is sleeping for short periods until a predefined point in time is reached:

  ```
  endtime = DateAdd("h", 4, Now)
  Do Until Now >= endtime
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop
  ```
- [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is pointless, particularly in weakly typed languages like VBScript.

Modified code:

```
Option Explicit

Const timeout   = 10 'seconds
Const sleeptime = 4  'hours
Const timeUp    = -1

Dim sh, rebootChoice, wmi, os, endtime

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do While True
  rebootChoice = sh.Popup("A system update requires a reboot. " & _
                          "Please reboot now by clicking Yes. " & _
                          "Choose No to be asked again in 4 hours.", timeout, _
                          "NOTICE - REBOOT REQUIRED", _
                          vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbDefaultButton2)

  Select Case rebootChoice
    Case vbYes
      Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
                          "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}!" & _
                          "\\.\root\cimv2")
      For Each os In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
        os.Reboot 1
      Next
    Case vbNo, timeUp
      endtime = DateAdd("h", sleeptime, Now)
      Do Until Now >= endtime
        WScript.Sleep 500
      Loop
  End Select
Loop
```

Note that in the current form "No" is the default choice, so without user interaction the system will never reboot. If you want to change the default to make the system reboot when the user does nothing, move `timeUp` to the other case:

Default "No":

```
Case vbYes
  ...
Case vbNo, timeUp
  ...
```

Default "Yes":

```
Case vbYes, timeUp
  ...
Case vbNo
  ...
```

Also remove `+ vbDefaultButton2` from the `Popup` statement to make <kbd>Enter</kbd> select "Yes" instead of "No".

Comment: +1, Good suggestions. But the last paragraph is wrong. Without user interaction the PopUp method returns -1, not the value associated with the default button (7 in this case). The `vbDefaultButton...` options just select the default button in the interface, that will be the control selected if the user directly press `Enter`